# casting from variabble type to referencce to variable

Tags: c++, casting, reference, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

```
ValueType& operator[](const KeyType& key) {
            Node<Pair> *cur_node = this->_head;
            while (cur_node != nullptr) {
                if (cur_node->Data().first == key) {
                    //ValueType& ref = cur_node->Data().second;
                    return cur_node->Data().second;
                }
                cur_node = cur_node->Next();
                int a = 5;
                int& ra = a;
            }
```

Hi, ValueType is defined as class of the template in which this operator is implemented. In my case it is int. "second" is also from type ValueType (not reference). I do need to return a reference from the function to the object of class ValueType;

The error:

```
return: cannot cast from int to int&
```

Although the simple example with a and ra do complie. Initializing ref and returning it like in comment also gives the same error, how do I handle it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that the method Data() didn't return data by reference.